# contact form em HTML e PHP

Tags: php, html

Criei uma contact form em HTML :

```
<form id="contactform" method="post" action="contact_form.php">
<h3> Get in touch</h3>
    <h4> Fill in the form below, and we'll get back to you as soon as possible</h4>

<label>Name</label>
<input name="name" placeholder="Type here" required>

<label>Email</label>
<input name="email" placeholder="Please enter your email address" required>

    <label>Message:</label>
    <textarea name="message" placeholder="Type here" required></textarea>

<input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
```

E depois fiz post para uma pagina em PHP:

```
<?php
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $from = 'From: galaxybooks'; 
    $to = 'xx@gmail.com'; 
    $subject = 'contact';
    $human = $_POST['human'];

    $body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message";

    if ($_POST['submit'] && $human == '4') {                 
        if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) { 
        echo '<p>Your message has been sent!</p>';
    } else { 
        echo '<p>Something went wrong, go back and try again!</p>'; 
    } 
    } else if ($_POST['submit'] && $human != '4') {
    echo '<p>You answered the anti-spam question incorrectly!</p>';
    }
?>
```

por questões de privacidade mudei aqui o email, mas o email que estou usando é um email valido. quando clico submeter, recebo a mensagem de que a mensagem foi enviada com sucesso, mas a realidade e que não estou a receber nada no meu email. Alguma sugestão?
Obrigado

Comment: Pergunta básica: já verificou a caixa de spam de seu e-mail? E não existe um campo no formulário chamado `human`, o que seria isso?

Comment: foi a primeira coisa que fiz!

Comment: faz assim, comenta  //$human = $_POST['human']; e coloca abaixo dele     $human = 4; e veja se recebe email na sua caixa

Comment: voce sugere que eu elimine  $human = $_POST['human']; e substitua por   $human = 4?

Comment: não, comenta ele com duas barras //$human = $_POST['human']; e coloca abaixo dele $human = 4;

Comment: vou ter q dar uma saída, mas deixei uma resposta. Não esqueça de descomentar  $human = $_POST['human']  e elimibar $human = 4;

Comment: Fiz uma edição na resposta explicando o que estava ocorrendo no seu código

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> O PHP está requisitando um valor de um campo de name human

```
$human = $_POST['human'];
```

> Só que este campo no seu HTML não existe

**Portanto acrescente um campo no seu HTML com name human como por exemplo**

```
<h3>I'm not a robot. 2 + 2 is</h3>
<input name="human" placeholder="Type here" required>
```

**HTML**

```
  <form id="contactform" method="post" action="contact_form.php">
    <h3>I'm not a robot. 2 + 2 is</h3>
    <input name="human" placeholder="Type here" required>

    <h3> Get in touch</h3>
    <h4> Fill in the form below, and we'll get back to you as soon as possible</h4>

    <label>Name</label>
    <input name="name" placeholder="Type here" required>

    <label>Email</label>
    <input name="email" placeholder="Please enter your email address" required>

    <label>Message:</label>
    <textarea name="message" placeholder="Type here" required></textarea>

    <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: não funcionou :s

Comment: Muito obrigado funcionou mesmo. então por aquilo que eu entendo é que faltava colocar a verificação no HTML é isso?agradeço que me explique, agora está a funcionar o que é optimo mas preciso entender.uma vez mais obrigado

Comment: Fiz uma edição na resposta explicando o que estava ocorrendo no seu código